# How to get value from react-flatpickr in react.js

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get the date onChange from a `react-flatpickr`,
[Docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-flatpickr) suggest doing this way

```
const { date } = this.state;
    return (
      <Flatpickr
        data-enable-time
        value={date}
        onChange={date => {
          this.setState({ date });
        }}
```

But I'm using useState for other inputs and do not want to do as they explained it.
This is how I'm trying to get

```
     <FormGroup>
       <Label className="py-1">Select Date</Label>
          <Flatpickr
            defaultValue={new Date()}
            data-enable-time
            name="goodsreadyby"
            className={classnames('form-control')}
            onChange={(e) => {setNewDate({e})}}
             />
         </FormGroup>
```

But I'm getting `undefined` value from this approach. Does anybody know how to fix that?

Comment: Try to console.log(e) or console.log(e.target.value) in onChange to see what you have got, also I've noticed you missed the value attribute on the Flatpickr

Comment: Used `defaultValue={new Date()}` for that purpose of value, doing the same thing, Tried another way as well with the value same result, It's giving undefined value,

Answer (score 1):

The `onChange` event should be added to options, then it works:

```js
const options = {
  onChange: (selectedDates, dateStr, instance) => alert(dateStr)
}

<Flatpickr options={options} />
```